# How to implement this kotlin ReceiveChannel code properly

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am following a tutorial where the teacher uses the `ProducerJob` method to demonstrate kotlin coroutine but my IDE says that method is deprecated and I should use `ReceiveChannel` instead but that also says I should use a **extensions on the coroutinescope instead** but I can seem to be unable to implement that correctly.

Here the instructor's code:

```
fun produceNumbers() : ProducerJob<Int> = produce {

    for (x in 1..5) {
        println("send $x")
        send(x)
    }
    println("Done")

} 

fun main() = runBlocking{
    val channel = produceNumbers()
    channel.consumeEach {
        println(it)
    }
    println("Main done")

}
```

And here is my code:

```
fun produceNumbers() : ReceiveChannel<Int> = produce {

        for (x in 1..5) {
            println("send $x")
            send(x)
        }
    println("Done")

}

fun main() = runBlocking{
    val channel = produceNumbers()
    channel.consumeEach {
        println(it)
    }
    println("Main done")

}
```

Does your code compile: Yes
Version: kotlinx-coroutines-core-0.27.0.eap13

Comment: Does your code compile? Which version of the coroutines library are you using? What are your imports? I don't think you can call `produce` like this without a `CoroutineScope` in recent versions of the coroutines library.

Comment: Just to add, this where ProducerJob was fully deprecated https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/commit/49b97d0a0eb3d9f8b32976677e769ee784fd2a29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is recommended to declare your function as extension of `CoroutineScope` is that you need a scope for any coroutine-creating built-in function anyway. You should not be able to call `produce` without a scope, it should not compile in recent versions of Kotlin coroutines library.

Declaring your function as extension of `CoroutineScope` is done this way:

```
fun CoroutineScope.produceNumbers() : ReceiveChannel<Int> = produce {
    for (x in 1..5) {
        println("send $x")
        send(x)
    }
    println("Done")
}
```

If you are not using it in an extension of `CoroutineScope` then you'll need to either provide a scope another way (like a field of an enclosing class, or method param), or use the `GlobalScope`, both of which are not recommended. The extension-based version above is a pattern that is recognizable and intuitive for coroutine users.

A more "reactive" approach would be using [flows](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) instead of channels:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

fun produceNumbers() : Flow<Int> = flow {
    for (x in 1..5) {
        println("emit $x")
        emit(x)
    }
    println("Done")
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val flow = produceNumbers()
    flow.collect {
        println(it)
    }
    println("Main done")
}
```

Note that this will behave differently though, as it wont be started in a concurrent coroutine unless explicitly stated (e.g. using
[`flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html)
, or replacing the `flow {...}` by a [`channelFlow {...}`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html).

Comment: where will the flowOn() be used?

Comment: On user side `val flow = produceNumbers().flowOn(Dipsatchers.Default)` will run the flow's code in the default dispatcher (in a thread pool), while `collect()` will still run on the main thread, so you get parallelism here. There must be other ways to get it to run concurrently without parallelism, but none come to mind right now.

Comment: Thank you and do you have any link to the flow doc?

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html

Comment: I added some links to the answer. Maybe you can look up `channelFlow` and `produceIn` if you want interactions between channels and flows.